# form_for not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model called "ExpDemo" and want to use it from "MainController."

I setup the code like this:

main_controller.rb

```
def pre
  @demo = ExpDemo.new
end
```

main/pre.html.erb

```
<% form_for(@demo) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Until here, I experienced 'path' error.

```
undefined method `exp_demos_path'
```

So, I added following to routes.rb and the error message gone.

```
resources :exp_demos
```

Now, the form is not showing up in the HTML page.
I think the routing setup is the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you forgot an `=` for the form_for

```
<%= form_for(@demo) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Oops! I didn't notice that :) I've been looking for it for 30 mins :( Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Change `<% form_for` to `<%= form_for`

---

**Explanation:**

`<% %>` Executes ruby code that doesn't output results

`<%= %>` Executes
   ruby code and outputs HTML

In other words, your form is created (which is why there is no error shown) but not printed as HTML.